# Wordpress theme is not updating for anonyous users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a fresh WordPress 3.5 version installed in hostgator, and when I change the 2011 theme to 2012 them , and check with a anonymous user , the theme is not updating to him.

I can't understand why this is happening. I have installed the following plugins

- Akismet
- Float Left Right Advertising
- Hello Dolly
- Infinite Scroll
- Jetpack by WordPress.com [ACTIVE]
- WP Super Cache [ACTIVE]

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear cache for W3 Total Cache plugin.

Go to Performance -> Empty all caches

Clear your browser cache

Restart httpd Apache server if required

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache within the *WP Super Cache* plugin and it will work fine.